# How to to convert a single column into multiple columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert a single column into multiple columns.

```
Set rng1 = Range("A3")
Set rng2 = Range("A16")
Set rng3 = Range("B3")
Set rng4 = Range("A16")

For Each R In Intersect(Range("A1:A5000"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    If InStr(R, "Sunday") > 0 Then

        Range("C1").Value = 5

        If rng2.Row > rng1.Row Then
            Range("C1").Value = 6
            Range("F3").EntireColumn.Insert
            Range("F3").EntireColumn.Insert
            Range("C1").Value = 9
            Range(rng2, rng3.End(xlUp)).Cut
            Range("C1").Value = 10
            Range("F3").PasteSpecial
            Range("C1").Value = 7
```

It consistently fails at the PasteSpecial line.

> Run-time Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

I'm currently working off the assumption that it's trying to paste it above A1.

The reason behind going up from the bottom is so I can offset a line on the bottom of each new column.

EDIT: Tried removing PasteSpecial and just pasting it using the cut method, but it still fails.

EDIT: Tried the line

```
Range("F1").Value2 = Range(rng2, rng3.End(xlUp)).Value2
```

As a replacement for cutting and pasting, still throws me the same error. Though the code continues on past it. It also doesn't paste anything.

EDIT: Uhh, so, it does copy entries over now, but not the values I want, and only a single one.

Comment: I don't think you can use `PasteSpecial` after `.Cut`. You can't do this manually either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you bypass the paste method by directly assigning values from one cell to another:

```
Sheet2.Range("A2:B3").value2 = Sheet1.Range("A2:B3").value2
```

Is faster and cleaner, it can also be used with arrays and variables. So you can split the range within how many arrays you want, and then use the code above to take the values into desired columns.

Comment: Upvote - I highly recommend avoiding cutting and pasting altogether where possible

Comment: I assume this can be used with variables? Just gave it a try and it still throws a wobbly, most likely me being inept though.

Comment: Please review the expression Range("F1").value2, you need to define the whole range to which you want to assign the values eg. Range("F1:J5")